# Storm spout stops emitting when second supervisor node added

Tags: apache-storm, trident

I am using `TridentTopology` to read from a file and emit aggregates using a single spout. When I have a single supervisor node, the topology is working fine and spout is emitting fine. However when a second supervisor node is added, the spout stops emitting. I was able to verify that there are two supervisor nodes using Storm UI. There are no errors either in supervisor log or worker log files on both the nodes.

Comment: To put it accurately, spout is emitting but the execute() method of class overriding BaseFunction is not getting executed. Also Storm UI does not show any tuples getting emitted.